# Environment variables in Podspec

Tags: cocoapods

I have an open source library that is build automatically by a CI system, and deployed in trunk/cocoapods automatically by the CI itself.

I would like to reduce the human-error possibility in the library version. 
Currently, when a new release is ready I have to go inside the podspec and manually modify the `version` tag.

Since the CI automatically release the library for every new git-tag, **is there a way to use the CI environment variables in the podspec?**.

In particular I tried the following:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
.......
 s.version      = ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
......
```

But doesn't seems to work.

Any ideas how to use environment variables for it?

Something better then a text search-replace script maybe :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and tries this seems to work for me:

```
s.version      = "#{ ENV['CI_COMMIT_TAG'] }"
```

Comment: The problem was that it needs spaces before and after the brackets.